# animate css gradient array

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a parent div the width of the screen with a set height. I want to animate smaller boxes of equal length inside it. I want to 'slide' the color of the smaller boxes with single a gradient for the parent div. This is one way I have implemented it with every box being a div with variable width:

[image: tele]

It has issues with mobile display so I need a new solution.
I know that animating gradients with background position is possible, but what about animating *portions* of a gradient at a time.

The final version of this would include about 100 smaller boxes inside this div.I am looking for advice so if this makes more sense to just do in a canvas please let me know.

Comment: you cannot, but you have background-size that works . a mixed of bg position/size/repeat or multiple gradient should do

Comment: You can't animate gradients like that. Use child divs or `canvas`.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: here is my idea of size/position/repeat http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqyGYP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with each box being an individual gradient and then animate that gradient's `background-size`. However, I wouldn't recommend doing this. Animating 100 gradients is bound to be pretty bad for performance. As is animating the `width` of 100 elements (animating a `scale()` transform for each `div` would be better in that case).

If `canvas` is an option, then yes, use `canvas`, it's a much better choice in this case, both from a maintainability and from a performance point of view.

Comment: If there are say 20 rows that each contain one of these animated divs, would using `canvas` still be manageable for mobile devices? Only one would animate at a time, but they all need to be rendered on the same page

Answer (score 0):

If the boxes are equal length, you can animate just the main background, using steps: (hover the div)

```css
.test {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow 50%, green 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0;
  transition: background-position 40s steps(100);
}
.test:hover {
  background-position: -100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```